# Unnamed programs in program list on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu

I have found unnamed programs in my xubuntu program list. Looks very strange, because before it wasn't there. Could anybody explain that and how to manually find that programs?

Since I cannot post images, please look image here:

[image]

Comment: Please add output of `grep -ir unnamed /usr/share/applications /usr/lib/mime/packages ~/.local/share/applications` to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1254001/edit).

Comment: no output when type it on terminal and click enter